# Formatting mark-up output using div tags instead that html table, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to ask for help formatting the HTML output generated by jQuery code, using div tags instead that a table.

This is the current output:

```
 Box #01
 Box #02
 1
 2
```

I need the output to be:

```
 Box #01    1
 Box #02    2
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyyyzd7v/4/) shows the jquery and the mark-up.

Ideally I would like to achieve the same effect using only div tags. 
If someone knows a way to do this, it would be great to read your ideas.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please include your code in the actual question.

Comment: I included the fiddle that has the sample html. I thought I needed to include that.

Comment: use css `display:table` property http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Fiddles are great and do include them, but you should also post the code in the question itself (future proof in case jsfiddle isn't available someday).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just update your code:

```
$.each($('.ShoppingCart'), function (i,j) {
 var cab = $(this).html();    
 $.each($('.shoppingCart_qty-select'), function (k,v) {
    if(i==k){  
      $("#test").append(cab + " " + $.trim($(this).find('option').html()) + "</br>");
    }
 });
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/fyyyzd7v/10/

Comment: All the proposed answers are good and work. I am not sure how to mark this questions as answered.

Comment: Just choose the more suitable to your needs, we all are glad to help, so don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/fyyyzd7v/6/) is your solution.

use this css

```
.ShoppingCart{
    float:left;
}
.shoppingCart_Category{
    float:left;
}
.shoppingCart_qtyLabel{
    display:inline-block;
}
br{
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like below.

```
 div { /* Use your id's or classes */
    min-width: 80px;
    display: inline-table;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fyyyzd7v/8/)

**Note:** Adjust to suit your need

Answer (score 1):

Here's your updated fiddle,  http://jsfiddle.net/fyyyzd7v/9/

If I were going to do this, I'd put each description and quantity inside a div rather than having two columns of data separated by line breaks, but this will give you an idea of formatting it.  I just used display block and float left and right.

CSS:

```
#orderWrapper {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

#itemOrderPreview {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

#qtyOrderPreview {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
}
```

I changed your HTML a little

```
<div id="orderWrapper">
    <div id="itemOrderPreview"></div>
    <div id="qtyOrderPreview"></div>
</div>
```